# Ray intersection length with random 3D box

Tags: c, math

I have a 3d box random in space and know the nodes of it. A ray is intersecting this box. I would like to know the length of this intersection and have no idea how to code this in C or describing it mathematically.

Comment: The box is a set of faces. [Solve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93plane_intersection) for every face, the distance is the shortest length that intersects. C itself has no particular features which make this easy.

Comment: This is probably rather a question for [this forum](https://math.stackexchange.com/). Also the term "3d box" is very vague.

Answer (score 1):

This can be broken down into 3 parts:

a) Use "formula for intersection between line and plane" to determine if/where ray hits each plane; where each plane is determined from 3 vertices of the box (from each face of the box)

b) Determine if the intersection point for each plane (if any) is inside or outside the corresponding face of the box. For this I'd flatten everything to 2D (e.g. discard x, y or z for the plane's vertices and its intersection point, depending on which part of the plane's surface normal is largest); then pick a direction (e.g. "towards +x") and see if a line (in 2D space) from the intersection point heading in the chosen direction hits one edge of the face (and not zero edges or 2 edges). From this you get a list of intersections with faces of the box.

c) Find the closest "intersections with faces of box". This is mostly just a simplified Pythagoras thing ("`distance_squared = distance_x * distance_x + distance_y * distance_y + distance_z * distance_z`") with some "if(distance_squared < best_distance_squared_seen_so_far)".

Note 1: This method works for arbitrary objects/meshes with any number of faces (not just boxes); however if you wanted to support concave polygons (for faces) you'd need to determine if (after flattening to 2D) a line from the intersection point heading in a chosen direction hits an odd number of edges (and not just one edge).

Note 2: There's a tricky case where (after flattening to 2D) a line from the intersection point heading in a chosen direction hits a vertex perfectly. In this case you need to determine if it hits an edge or misses both edges by determining if both edges leading from the vertex are on the same side of your line. I don't think you need to care about this case for boxes (and can assume "hits vertex = hits an edge") but would need to care about it for arbitrary objects/meshes.